# Blank Unit Circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to adapt the following code so that the angles (Degree and radian) along with the coordinates are blank.  I have tried to change some of the code, but I don't know if there is an easier way.

```latex
% Unit circle
% Author: Supreme Aryal
% A unit circle with cosine and sine values for some
% common angles.
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
     \draw[->] (-1.5cm,0cm) -- (1.5cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
             \draw[->] (0cm,-1.5cm) -- (0cm,1.5cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};

        % draw the unit circle
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);

        \foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
                % lines from center to point
                \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:1cm);
                % dots at each point
                \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
                % draw each angle in degrees
                \draw (\x:0.6cm) node[fill=white] {$\x^\circ$};
        }

        % draw each angle in radians
        \foreach \x/\xtext in {
            30/\frac{\pi}{6},
            45/\frac{\pi}{4},
            60/\frac{\pi}{3},
            90/\rule{.5in}{.5pt},
            120/\frac{2\pi}{3},
            135/\frac{3\pi}{4},
            150/\frac{5\pi}{6},
            180/\pi,
            210/\frac{7\pi}{6},
            225/\frac{5\pi}{4},
            240/\frac{4\pi}{3},
            270/\frac{3\pi}{2},
            300/\frac{5\pi}{3},
            315/\frac{7\pi}{4},
            330/\frac{11\pi}{6},
            360/2\pi}
                \draw (\x:0.85cm) node[fill=white] {$\xtext$};

        \foreach \x/\xtext/\y in {
            % the coordinates for the first quadrant
            30/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
            45/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            60/\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the second quadrant
            150/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
            135/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            120/-\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the third quadrant
            210/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
            225/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            240/-\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the fourth quadrant
            330/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
            315/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            300/\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
                \draw (\x:1.25cm) node[fill=white] {$\left(\xtext,\y\right)$};

        % draw the horizontal and vertical coordinates
        % the placement is better this way
        \draw (-1.25cm,0cm) node[above=1pt] {\(\big(\rule{.25in}{1pt},\rule{.25in}{1pt}\big)\)};
              (1.25cm,0cm)  node[above=1pt] {}
              (0cm,-1.25cm) node[fill=white] {};
              (0cm,1.25cm)  node[fill=white] {\(\big(\rule{.25in}{1pt},\rule{.25in}{1pt}\big)\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: What do you mean with “blank”? If you don't want to have text, remove the `node`s (and with them the `\foreach` loops that generate them.

Comment: Please clarify, what you after. Just draw segmented circle? If this a case remove all nodes data from loops and loops minimize to `\foreach \x in {...}` .

Comment: I would like my students to fill in a blank unit circle, like the one found here, I just would like to create it using Tikz, http://www.embeddedmath.com/downloads/files/unitcircle/blankunitcircle-letter.pdf   You can see in the lower left of my code that I have a blank ordered pair for the students to fill in. I want that to replace the ordered pair at 4pi/3

Comment: @NickB You could just put all numbers into `\phantom{…}` (but leave out things like `^\circ`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hm, like this?

[image]

For this you only need to add option `text=white` to nodes in all loops:

```
node[fill=white, text=white]
```

BTW, can you add source of your code?

**Addendum (improved):**
I would make framed nodes, simplified (my) code and center  image on page:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.5,
                        >={Stealth[scale=2]},
lbl/.append style = {draw=#1, fill=white, font=\large, text=white, 
                     minimum height=3ex, inner xsep=5pt, inner ysep=2pt}
                ]
\draw[->] (-1.5cm,0cm) -- (1.5cm,0cm) node[right,font=\Large] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0cm,-1.4cm) -- (0cm,1.4cm) node[above,font=\Large] {$y$};

% draw the unit circle
\draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);

% draw angle in degrees and radians, draw x and y vale
\foreach \id/\ir/\x/\y in {
    30/\frac{\pi}{6}/\frac{1}{2} /\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    45/\frac{\pi}{4}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    60/\frac{\pi}{3}/\frac{1}{2} /\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    90/\frac{\pi}{2}/0/1,
    120/\frac{2\pi}{3}/-\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    135/\frac{3\pi}{4}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    150/\frac{5\pi}{6}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
    180/\pi/-1/0,
    210/\frac{7\pi}{6}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
    225/\frac{5\pi}{4}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    240/\frac{4\pi}{3}/-\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    270/\frac{3\pi}{2},
    300/\frac{5\pi}{3}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
    315/\frac{7\pi}{4}/\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
    330/\frac{11\pi}{6}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
    360/2\pi/1/0
    }
\draw (0,0) -- ++ (\id:6mm)     node[lbl=red]   {$\id$} 
            -- ++ (\id:2.2mm)   node[lbl=blue]  {$\ir$} 
            -- ++ (\id:4mm)     node[lbl=teal]  {$\left(\x,\y\right)$} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: The loop list can be shortened to `{0, 30, ..., 359, 45, 135, ..., 360}`. (`359` makes sure we don't do `0 = 360` twice, the `360` at the end is because I'm to lazy to calculate `135+90` and `360-45`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, thank you for tip. I will left as it is, that to OP the code will be more clear.

Comment: @Nick B, see improved addendum!

Answer (score 0):

I took @zarko's idea of filling text with white. I then added the 45 degree segments to complete the circle. I had to break the whole code to see what it does so I could make changes:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
     \draw[->] (-1.5cm,0cm) -- (1.5cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
             \draw[->] (0cm,-1.5cm) -- (0cm,1.5cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};

        % draw the unit circle
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); 
            \foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
                \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm) -- (\x:1cm);
                \draw (\x:0.6cm) node[fill=white,text=white] {$\x^\circ$};
                 \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.5pt);}
                    \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
            
            \foreach \x in {45,135,...,360} {
                \draw[gray] (0cm,0cm)--(\x:1cm);
                \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.5pt);
                \draw (\x:0.6cm) node[fill=white,text=white] {$\x^\circ$};}

            \foreach \x/\xtext in {
            30/\frac{\pi}{6},
            45/\frac{\pi}{4},
            60/\frac{\pi}{3},
            90/\frac{\pi}{2},
            120/\frac{2\pi}{3},
            135/\frac{3\pi}{4},
            150/\frac{5\pi}{6},
            180/\pi,
            210/\frac{7\pi}{6},
            225/\frac{5\pi}{4},
            240/\frac{4\pi}{3},
            270/\frac{3\pi}{2},
            300/\frac{5\pi}{3},
            315/\frac{7\pi}{4},
            330/\frac{11\pi}{6},
            360/2\pi}
                \draw (\x:0.85cm) node[fill=white,text=white] {$\xtext$};

        \foreach \x/\xtext/\y in {
            % the coordinates for the first quadrant
            30/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
            45/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            60/\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the second quadrant
            150/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
            135/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            120/-\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the third quadrant
            210/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
            225/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            240/-\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the fourth quadrant
            330/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
            315/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            300/\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
                \draw (\x:1.25cm) node[fill=white] 
                {$\Big(\rule{.25in}{.25pt},\rule{.25in}{.25pt}\Big)$};

        % draw the horizontal and vertical coordinates
        % the placement is better this way
        \draw (-1.25cm,0cm) node[above=1pt] {$(-1,0)$}
              (1.25cm,0cm)  node[above=1pt] {$(1,0)$}
              (0cm,-1.25cm) node[fill=white] {$(0,-1)$}
              (0cm,1.25cm)  node[fill=white] {$(0,1)$};
     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
   

        % draw each angle in radians
        \foreach \x/\xtext in {
            30/\frac{\pi}{6},
            45/\frac{\pi}{4},
            60/\frac{\pi}{3},
            90/\rule{.5in}{.5pt},
            120/\frac{2\pi}{3},
            135/\frac{3\pi}{4},
            150/\frac{5\pi}{6},
            180/\pi,
            210/\frac{7\pi}{6},
            225/\frac{5\pi}{4},
            240/\frac{4\pi}{3},
            270/\frac{3\pi}{2},
            300/\frac{5\pi}{3},
            315/\frac{7\pi}{4},
            330/\frac{11\pi}{6},
            360/2\pi}
                \draw (\x:0.85cm) node[fill=white] {$\xtext$};

        \foreach \x/\xtext/\y in {
            % the coordinates for the first quadrant
            30/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
            45/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            60/\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the second quadrant
            150/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
            135/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            120/-\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the third quadrant
            210/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
            225/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            240/-\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the fourth quadrant
            330/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
            315/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            300/\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
                \draw (\x:1.25cm) node[fill=white] {$\left(\xtext,\y\right)$};

        % draw the horizontal and vertical coordinates
        % the placement is better this way
        \draw (-1.25cm,0cm) node[above=1pt] {\(\big(\rule{.25in}{1pt},\rule{.25in}{1pt}\big)\)};
              (1.25cm,0cm)  node[above=1pt] {}
              (0cm,-1.25cm) node[fill=white] {};
              (0cm,1.25cm)  node[fill=white] {\(\big(\rule{.25in}{1pt},\rule{.25in}{1pt}\big)\)};

'''
```